# Not shown TextView after setting VISIBLE from GONE in animation

Tags: android, animation, layout, visible

trying to make showing LinarLayout from GONE state to VISIBLE with "roll down" animation. On this Layout exist TextView. Seems to all work fine but, a TextView not shown after animation.
What I do wrong?

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/ll_info">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bayer_note"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/buyer_note"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_continue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/button_register"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cont_caption"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Войти"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:fontFamily="fonts/SF-UI-Display-Regular.ttf"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_door"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_cont_caption"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

And animation code:

```
final LinearLayout ll_info = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_info);

        class scaleAnimation extends Animation {
                    public LinearLayout ll;
                    public int newHeight;

                    public void scaleTopHeight(int height)
                    {
                        newHeight = height;
                    }

                    public void setLayout(LinearLayout layout) {
                        ll = layout;
                    }
                }

                final LinearLayout ll_info = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_info);

                scaleAnimation h = new scaleAnimation() {
                    @Override
                    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                        ll.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                                ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                : (int)(newHeight * interpolatedTime);
                        ll.requestLayout();
                    }
                };
                h.setDuration(300);
                h.setLayout(ll_info);
        ll_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll_info.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((LinearLayout)ll_info.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((LinearLayout)ll_info.getParent()).getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
                h.scaleTopHeight(ll_info.getMeasuredHeight());
        ll_info.getLayoutParams().height=1;
                ll_info.startAnimation(h);
```

Comment: Try to change textColor of your textview, if it might help.

Comment: @Drv, after animation TextView not exist and LinearLayout on wich this TextView lay has smaller heigh. I think reason not in text colour...

Comment: You need to write proper code for setting height of your linearlayout.

Comment: @Drv, what I do wrong?

Comment: Sry but I really don't get what are you trying to do, so I'm unable to help.

Comment: @Drv, I want to show LinearLayout ll_info from invisible state with animation by button click.

Comment: If you want simple animation for visible-gone of your layout then use android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in your LinearLayout. But remember if you write this line, your custom animation will not work then.

Comment: Write android:animateLayoutChanges="true"  in your layout file and in your onClick method write only ll_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); It will be visible with som defaultanimation.

Comment: @Drv, this is work fine, buI I need my animation...

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"

            **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** /////
```

> ***remove this***

```
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/button_register"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_cont_caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Войти"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="fonts/SF-UI-Display-Regular.ttf"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_door"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_cont_caption"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

i think this is your xml file issue ,your relativelayout in center_horizontal and all the childs are in center in parent.so textview hides over imageview. Try it and let me know.

Comment: sorry, but not this text view is not showing. id.buyer_note not visible. but if I don't set Visibly GONE, then after Activity start all view has correct sizes and visibility. But I need show ll_info only by Button click. And If I change in Desing time Visibility to GONE and make visibility VISIBLE on runtime ll_info layout shows but w/o TextView id.buyer_info.